# Personalised Whatsapp message to masses from google spreadsheet database

Tags: twilio

I have been trying to personalize my messages and send in masses to my customers in google spreadsheet through whatsapp. Have been trying to work on this with an expert but it seems that currently they only allow twilio number which we have to buy from them. May I check whether any of you know when twilio will be able to enable non-twilio number(our personal contact number) for the whatsapp?

Comment: "Masses"?  Did you mean "messages"?

Comment: No, masses = large groups of people

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp does not support certain uses cases, so verify this is this a promotional use case.

You will need to WhatsApp enable a Twilio number. Based on where you are located, [porting your number to Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/categories/203267567-Porting) may be an option.

[WhatsApp Commerce Policy](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/commerce-policy/)

[What use cases and businesses are allowed to use WhatsApp on Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039737793-What-use-cases-and-businesses-are-allowed-to-use-WhatsApp-on-Twilio-).

Comment: Thank you very much. Will try and ask my expert with regards to this, thanks